# QNX USB Utility not found?

Tags: qnx

I have a physical box with QNX 6.3.0 installed.  PS/2 mice and keyboard work fine.   I'm trying to see if I can get a USB mouse going.  What info I could find seemed to say I should start with:

`usb -vvv`

However, I get this:

```
$ usb
/bin/sh: usb: not found
```

Where's the usb utility supposed to be installed at, and why is it not found?  Isn't it supposed to be a default utility?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try for :

`cd /fs/usb0` In my case this usb0 is the desired name . you can change accordingly .